# How can I get IP address of the requested site in JSP code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, networking, network-programming

My task is to determine is there NAT between client and web-server or not.
I am using this algorithm:

1. User requests web-page
2. JSP code runs and obtains IP of the requested site
3. JSP code gets the internal IP of the server
4. I compare two IPs and if they are the same - it means no NAT

**My question is: how can I get IP address of requested site in JSP code?**
I tryed to use **request.getRequestURL()**, but it returned domen's name of site.
Also I tryed to get header **Host** of the request, but it didn't work neither.
Moreover, I have specific server without DNS service, that's why I can't get IP of DNS name.

Or any ideas how can I determine is there NAT between client and server?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29).

Description says:

> Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request. For HTTP servlets, same as the value of the CGI variable REMOTE_ADDR.

**Note**: This only gets you (or tries to) the client IP address. Not that of the server requested by the client.

Comment: Yea ... but that only gives you the source IP address of TCP connection.  If there is NATing (or a proxy), that won't be the browser's true IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The JSP code can't, because it runs on the server.

I assume that you actually mean Javascript code in the page created by the JSP, but I don't think that untrusted Javascript is allowed to find out the browser's IP address or hostname.

(There is one trick that is used to get *an* IP address for the client in javascript, but it involves sending a request to a remote server ... and in your case a remote server can only deliver NATed address.  Another trick involves running a Java applet, but I suspect that that will run into sandbox restrictions too ... unless the user's browser trusts the applet.)

In short, I don't think that it is normally possible for the server to find out if a client's IP address is NATed.

---

Note that if you do find out the true IP address behind a NATed address, it probably won't be any use to you.  The chances are that the IP address won't be routeable (because it is in a private range and/or behind a firewall), and it won't have a name in any public DNS server.